# Valgrind and memory leak in CPP: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values"

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

This code compiles and runs, creating the expected output, except when valgrind is run, then these memory leaks appear.  The following code runs on Visual Studio without any warnings or errors coming up.

So my question is, where is this memory leak occurring?  I'm relatively new to CPP and have spent hours on this, and so these errors are catching me by surprise.

Is there anything I am doing wrong in terms of the sequence?  Am I passing an uninitialized value somewhere?  Confused.

I am having trouble figuring out where the memory loss is occurring.  Here are the files:

```
/// Saiyan.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Saiyan.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sdds
{
    // CONSTRUCTORS:
    Saiyan::Saiyan()
    {
        // default state
        m_name = nullptr;   // Dynamic allocation:  set to nullptr!
        m_dob = 0;
        m_power = 0;
        m_super = false;
        m_level = 0;
    }
    
    Saiyan::Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power)
    {
        set(name, dob, power);
    }

    // MEMBER FUNCTIONS:
    void Saiyan::set(const char* name, int dob, int power, int level, bool super)
    {
        // Check if arguments are valid:
        if (name == nullptr || strlen(name) <= 0 || dob > 2020 || power <= 0)
        {
            *this = Saiyan();   // Calls constructor that creates default.
        }
        else
        {
            // Deallocate previosly allocated memory for m_name to avoid memory leak:
            if (m_name != nullptr && strlen(name) == 0)
            {
                delete[] m_name;
                m_name = nullptr;
            }
            // Assign validate values to current object:
            m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
            strcpy(m_name, name);
            m_dob = dob;
            m_power = power;
            m_super = super;
            m_level = level;
        }
    }
    
    bool Saiyan::isValid() const
    {
        bool valid_state = m_name != nullptr && strlen(m_name) > 0 && m_dob < 2020 && m_power > 0;
        return valid_state;
    }

    void Saiyan::display() const
    {
        if (isValid())
        {
            cout << m_name << endl;
            
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout.width(10);
            cout << "DOB: " << m_dob << endl;
            cout.width(10);
            cout << "Power: " << m_power << endl;
            cout.width(10);
            if (m_super == true) {
                cout << "Super: " << "yes" << endl;
                cout.width(10);
                cout << "Level: " << m_level;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Super: " << "no";
            }
            cout.unsetf(ios::left);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Saiyan!";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    bool Saiyan::fight(Saiyan& other)
    {
        // Check both Saiyans for super level and power up accordingly:
        if (m_super == true)
        {
            m_power += int(m_power * (.1 * m_level));   // Cast an int to avoid possible memory loss.
        }
        if (other.m_super == true)
        {
            other.m_power += int(other.m_power * (.1 * other.m_level));
        }

        bool value = m_power > other.m_power;
        return value;
    }

    // DESTRUCTOR:
    Saiyan::~Saiyan()
    {
        if (m_name != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] m_name;    // Deallocate memory of member.
            m_name = nullptr;
        }
    }
}



// Saiyan.h

#pragma once
#ifndef SDDS_SAIYAN_H
#define SDDS_SAIYAN_H

namespace sdds
{
    class Saiyan
    {
        char* m_name;       // Dynamically allocated array of chars.
        int m_dob;          // Year the Saiyan was born.
        int m_power;        // Integer indicating the strength of the Saiyan (>= 0).
        bool m_super;       // indicates whether Saiyan can evolve
        int m_level;        // an integer indicating the level of a SS

        /*
        ***Valid Name*** : a dynamically allocated array of chars.
        ***Valid Year of Birth***: an integer within the interval[0, 2020].
        ***Valid Power***: an integer that is greater than 0.
        */

    public:
        Saiyan();
        Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power);  // Custom constructor
        void set(const char* name, int dob, int power, int level = 0, bool super = false);
        bool isValid() const;
        void display() const;
        bool fight(Saiyan& other);  // Fight and power up Saiyans.
        ~Saiyan();
    };
}

#endif



// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Saiyan.h"
#include "Saiyan.h"  // this is on purpose

using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;

void printHeader(const char* title)
{
    char oldFill = cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "|> " << title << endl;

    cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout.fill(oldFill);
}


int main()
{
    {
        printHeader("T1: Checking default constructor");

        Saiyan theSayan;
        theSayan.display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T2: Checking custom constructor");

        Saiyan army[] = {
          Saiyan("Nappa", 2025, 1),
          Saiyan("Vegeta", 2018, -1),
          Saiyan("Goku", 1990, 200),
          Saiyan(nullptr, 2015, 1),
          Saiyan("", 2018, 5)
        };

        cout << "Only #2 should be valid:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "  Sayan #" << i << ": " << (army[i].isValid() ? "valid" : "invalid") << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            army[i].display();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // valid saiyans
    Saiyan s1("Goku", 1990, 2000);
    Saiyan s2;
    s2.set("Vegeta", 1989, 2200);

    {
        printHeader("T3: Checking the fight");
        s1.display();
        s2.display();

        cout << "S1 attacking S2, Battle " << (s1.fight(s2) ? "Won" : "Lost") << endl;
        cout << "S2 attacking S1, Battle " << (s2.fight(s1) ? "Won" : "Lost") << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T4: Checking powerup");
        s1.set("Goku", 1990, 1900, 1, true);
        int round = 0;
        bool gokuWins = false;
        while (!gokuWins) // with every fight, the super saiyan should power up
        {
            cout << "Round #" << ++round << endl;
            gokuWins = s1.fight(s2);
            s1.display();
            s2.display();
        }

        cout << "Bonus round. Is s2 winning? " << (s2.fight(s1) ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T5: Upgrading s2");
        s2.set("Vegeta", 1990, 2200, 3, true);

        cout << "Super Battle. Is s2 winning? " << (s2.fight(s1) ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
        s1.display();
        s2.display();
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what ended up working:

```
/// Saiyan.cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Saiyan.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sdds
{
    Saiyan::Saiyan()
    {
    }
    
    Saiyan::Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power)
    {
        set(name, dob, power);
    }

    void Saiyan::set(const char* name, int dob, int power, int level, bool super)
    {
        if (name != nullptr && name[0] != '\0')
        {
            if (m_name != nullptr)
            {
                delete[] m_name;
                m_name = nullptr;
            }
            m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
            strcpy(m_name, name);
        }
        if (dob != 0 && dob < 2020)
        {
            m_dob = dob;
        }
        if (power > 0)
        {
            m_power = power;
        }
        if (level > 0)
        {
            m_level = level;
        }
        m_super = super;
    }
    
    bool Saiyan::isValid() const
    {
        bool valid_state = m_name != nullptr && m_dob != 0 && m_dob < 2020 && m_power > 0 && m_level >= 0;
        return valid_state;
    }

    void Saiyan::display() const
    {
        if (isValid())
        {
            cout << m_name << endl;
            
            cout.setf(ios::right);
            cout.width(10);
            cout << "DOB: " << m_dob << endl;
            cout.width(10);
            cout << "Power: " << m_power << endl;
            cout.width(10);
            if (m_super == true) {
                cout << "Super: " << "yes" << endl;
                cout.width(10);
                cout << "Level: " << m_level;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Super: " << "no";
            }
            cout.unsetf(ios::left);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Saiyan!";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    bool Saiyan::fight(Saiyan& other)
    {
        // Check both Saiyans for super level and power up accordingly:
        if (m_super == true)
        {
            m_power += int(m_power * (.1 * m_level));   // Cast an int to avoid possible memory loss.
        }
        if (other.m_super == true)
        {
            other.m_power += int(other.m_power * (.1 * other.m_level));
        }

        bool value = m_power > other.m_power;
        return value;
    }

    Saiyan::~Saiyan()
    {
        if (m_name != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] m_name;    // Deallocate memory of member.
            m_name = nullptr;
        }
    }
}



// Saiyan.h
#pragma once
#ifndef SDDS_SAIYAN_H
#define SDDS_SAIYAN_H

namespace sdds
{
    class Saiyan
    {
        char* m_name{};     // Dynamically allocated array of chars.
        int m_dob{};                // Year the Saiyan was born.
        int m_power{};          // Integer indicating the strength of the Saiyan (>= 0).
        bool m_super{};     // indicates whether Saiyan can evolve
        int m_level{};          // an integer indicating the level of a SS

        /*
        ***Valid Name*** : a dynamically allocated array of chars.
        ***Valid Year of Birth***: an integer within the interval[0, 2020].
        ***Valid Power***: an integer that is greater than 0.
        */

    public:
        Saiyan();
        Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power);  // Custom constructor
        void set(const char* name, int dob, int power, int level = 0, bool super = false);
        bool isValid() const;
        void display() const;
        bool fight(Saiyan& other);  // Fight and power up Saiyans.
        ~Saiyan();
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: You can shorten `Saiyan::~Saiyan()
    {
        if (m_name != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] m_name;   
            m_name = nullptr;
        }
    }` to just `Saiyan::~Saiyan()
    {
            delete[] m_name;
    }` and you have the exact same result. `delete`ing a `nullptr` is a no-op and setting the member to `nullptr` in the destructor is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general --- avoid manual memory management, why not just use std::string?

Regarding issues in the code.

This part of code is a big no no:

```
        if (name == nullptr || strlen(name) <= 0 || dob > 2020 || power <= 0)
        {
            *this = Saiyan();   // Calls constructor that creates default.
        }
```

You are actually bypassing destructor here, so if m_name was initialized you will leak memory.

Another problem is in this constructor:

```
    Saiyan::Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power)
    {
        set(name, dob, power);
    }
```

You are not ensuring that your object will be in good state always after calling this constructor.

And last but not least, here:

```
            if (m_name != nullptr && strlen(name) == 0)
            {
                delete[] m_name;
                m_name = nullptr;
            }
```

You deallocate m_name only if new name is short, but you should deallocate regardless of new name length, as you are setting new value to m_name regardless of new name length.

Also in C++11 you can give default values to members outside of constructor and they will be used in each constructor in which you don't explicitly set different value:

```
    class Saiyan
    {
        char* m_name = nullptr; // Dynamically allocated array of chars.
        int m_dob = 0;          // Year the Saiyan was born.
        int m_power = 0;        // Integer indicating the strength of the Saiyan (>= 0).
        bool m_super = false;   // indicates whether Saiyan can evolve
        int m_level = 0;        // an integer indicating the level of a SS

    public:
        Saiyan() {};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Works!

```
    char* m_name = nullptr; // Dynamically allocated array of chars.
    int m_dob = 0;          // Year the Saiyan was born.
    int m_power = 0;        // Integer indicating the strength of the Saiyan (>= 0).
    bool m_super = false;   // indicates whether Saiyan can evolve
    int m_level = 0;        // an integer indicating the level of a SS
```